# Fits the diamond DIV to the parent DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am setting up a diamond div using CSS. But the diamond div is going out or the parent div.

Is there any way to calculate the diagonal length of the diamond div so I can set the width to the parent width?

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="ab-iconbar text-center">
        <div class="ab-baric">
            <img src="images/icons/baby63.svg" alt="baby">
        </div>
        <div class="ab-icobox">
            <h3>19<small>to</small>34</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.ab-iconbar {
    @extend .ab-bg-yellow;
    .ab-baric {
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        @extend .ab-bg-gsea; //bg color 
        text-align: center;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg);     
        img, .fa {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
        }
    }
    .ab-icobox {
        @extend .ab-c-midnit;
        padding: 10px;
    }
}
```

**JS**

```
var ab_icbar_w = $('.ab-iconbar').width();
var ab_baric_w = $('.ab-baric').css('width', ab_icbar_w);
$('.ab-baric').css('height', ab_baric_w);
```

**Current Output**

[image: Current Output]

Comment: Given that you effectively want to calculate the hypotenuse of a right angled triangle, it's simply `sqrt(a²+b²)` where `a` and `b` is the width and height of the square

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the Pythagorean theorem.

So

```js
var diagLength = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(width, 2) + Math.pow(height, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Pythagorus theorem would give you the diagonal length .
Get the height and width from jQuery,and use pythagorus theorem.